# What's wrong with this Buffon's needle geometric "solution"?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Suppose that one end of a needle is red and the other is blue. Let's assume the blue end is the right one when the needle is dropped on the floor. Now the blue end is on one of the strips (at some height) and the needle can lie only across the line that is the left edge of that strip. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgaQA.png) shows possible positions for both ends and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEuH.png) shows area of positions of the red end if the needle lies across the left line of the strip (darker area). If $l$ is the length of the needle and $t$ is the width of the strip, the probability in question is equal to:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}l^2\pi}{2lt}=\frac{l\pi}{4t}
$$
(In the images the radius of the semicircles is $l$ and the length of "the figure" is $t$).

What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This argument incorrectly assumes that the red end of the needle is uniformly distributed in the given region. If the *angle* of the needle is uniformly distributed, then the vertical distance between its endpoints is not. The red endpoint is more likely to fall within a small horizontal strip near the top or bottom of the region than in a strip of the same height near the middle.